# Android How to get hash key from created keystore for Foursquare

Tags: java, android, android-studio, foursquare

I am pretty new to Android development so sorry if this is simple and after some issues with creating the keystore i was able to create it, I see it in the terminal at /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_05.jdk/Contents/Home/bin folder how can I see the hash key value for this keystore? I need to enter the hash key into the foursquare website form in the Android Key Hashes field to setup the application as shown in

[Foursquare registration form](https://foursquare.com/developers/register)

Your help and feedback is appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Open your eclipse
2. go into Window menu
3. click on preferences
4. click  on Android
5. click on build

in right side you will find your keys if you already created your keystore file then browse that keystore file in last step and you will get your hash key.

Comment: Hi I use Android studio, where would i find it in there do you know? thanks for your help

Comment: ooops m not aware of it sorry